# disk copy software, imperfect disk

Tags: hard-drive, file-transfer

I didn't find this question, but if it is here let me know.

I have a problem disk.  I want to copy as much as possible from it before I scrap it.  But there are many thousands of files, so manually re-starting the copy every time it reaches a bad spot is not appealing.  I would like a copy program that will automatically go on to the next file when it reaches an unreadable one.  **Any suggestions for this?**

I have tried the following.  But none does what I want with this disk.  All will hang at some spot and apparently never recover, even if left overnight.

copy by drag 'n drop
Carbon Copy Cloner
SuperDuper!
Disk Utility
Tech Tool Pro
even some experiments with "cp -a" in the terminal  (but I'm no Unix expert)

Comment: In the end, it turned out that Disk Utility was pretty good for this.  When it hangs up, delete the bad file (and empty the trash).  Then start over.  There were only 4 or 5 bad files in the end, so it could proceed mostly unattended.  But of course if there is a way to do it completely unattended, that would be a good Answer!

Comment: See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/39504/6824