# Copy and move with Ultracopier without doing it through tray icon

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, file-transfer

So when you start Ultracopier this warning message shows up.

> The replacement of default copy/move system is not supported and blocked by finder of Mac OS X. You need do the copy/move manually by right clicking on the system tray icon near the clock (not the dock icon).

Is there a way of unblocking the default copy/move system and let ultracopier use it?

Comment: UltraCopier is considered [malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultracopier). Is there a special reason for you to use it?

Comment: wow, I did not know that. Well I'm looking for a software that can copy a huge amount of files and continue even if there is an error. The regular copy in osx doesn't do that. So essentially an osx alternative to TeraCopy.

Comment: please check [apple.stackexchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39504/best-way-to-copy-all-files-ignoring-errors)